Honda Civic 1.8l petrol engine 2007 - can ACEA C3 engine oil be used?
The manual says:

It is highly recommended that you use genuine Honda Motor Oil, "ACEA A1/B1", "ACEA A3/B3", or "ACEA A5/B5" in your vechicle for as long as you own it.

I accidentally bought ACEA C3 instead. Is this safe to use to top up the oil already in the engine (unknown type -- used car) and also in general, or should I go buy A3/B3 or A5/B5 instead?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

You really don't want to use C3 in your engine. C3 is specified for diesel engines in a light vehicle and for some performance vehicles. I mean, you could use it, but it wouldn't provide the same attributes as those specified for your vehicle. Your best bet would be to take the oil back to the retailer and get the correct oil specified for your engine.

I've ordered the correct oil in the meantime. In fact the oil I mentioned in the post is actually C2 not C3. Will it damage the engine if I just mix it in with the right oil a few cups at a time, until the incorrect 2L C2 engine oil bottle runs out?

That is, mix a few cups of C2 5W-30 with A3/B3 5w-30

@Daniel - Not sure why you'd want to? Really, I'd wait for the new oil and keep it like it should be. Oil of the same weight will provide lubrication to your engine, it just won't be providing the same amount of protection. Please note the warning under C2 (same for C3): WARNING:  these oils are unsuitable for use in some engines. ... That's a pretty firm reason why you probably don't want to be using it.

Yes, best to just get rid of the C2 then. Thank you
